# Why I am not getting a pass on my unit test

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have some code:

```
public class ProcessManager : IProcessManager
{
private readonly IFolderWatcher _folderWatcher;
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly Action<string> _action;
private readonly IReadFiles _readFiles;
private readonly IBankStatementComparisonManager _bankStatementComparisonManager;
private readonly IPrepareIncomingBankStatementRecords _prepareIncomingBankStatementRecords;

public ProcessManager(IFolderWatcher folderWatcher, ILogger logger,IReadFiles readFiles, IBankStatementComparisonManager bankStatementComparisonManager, IPrepareIncomingBankStatementRecords prepareIncomingBankStatementRecords)
{
    this._folderWatcher = folderWatcher;
    this._logger = logger;
    this._readFiles = readFiles;
    this._bankStatementComparisonManager = bankStatementComparisonManager;
    this._prepareIncomingBankStatementRecords = prepareIncomingBankStatementRecords;

    _action = ProcessFile;
}

public void Start() { StartMainProcess(); }

private void StartMainProcess()
{
    try
    {
    _folderWatcher.StartFolderWatcher(_action); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {    
    _logger.Error("Failed To Start Folder Watcher.  Shutting Down.");
    _logger.Error("Error Message: " + e.Message);
    _logger.Error("Inner Exception: " + e.InnerException);
    }
}
}
```

And a test:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockFolderWatcher = new Mock<IFolderWatcher>();
        var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
        var mockRFiles = new Mock<IReadFiles>();
        var mockBankStatementComparisonManager = new Mock<IBankStatementComparisonManager>();
        var mockPrepareIncomingBankStatementRecords = new Mock<IPrepareIncomingBankStatementRecords>();
        var mockAction = new Mock<Action<string>>();

        ProcessManager target = new ProcessManager(mockFolderWatcher.Object, mockLogger.Object, mockRFiles.Object, mockBankStatementComparisonManager.Object, mockPrepareIncomingBankStatementRecords.Object);

        //Act
        target.Start();

        //Assert
        mockFolderWatcher.Verify(m => m.StartFolderWatcher(mockAction.Object), Times.Once());
    }
```

When I run the test (in debug) I can see that the mockFolderWatcher.Invocations.Count = 1.
However my test fails and I get this error:

> Moq.MockException   HResult=0x80131500   Message= Expected invocation
>   on the mock once, but was 0 times: m =>
>   m.StartFolderWatcher(Action)

So why do I get a fail and the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion:

```
mockFolderWatcher.Verify(m => m.StartFolderWatcher(mockAction.Object), Times.Once());
```

Says that `StartFolderWatcher` **must** be called with that specific `Action` (`mockAction.Object`). This isn't the case: it's called with an `Action` which was created by the `ProcessManager`, and which points to its `ProcessFile` method.

You probably want to say "Verify that `StartFolderWatcher` was called with *any* `Action`":

```
mockFolderWatcher.Verify(m => m.StartFolderWatcher(It.IsAny<Action<string>>()), Times.Once());
```

---

By default, Moq accepts any calls which you haven't set up expectations for (you can change this by specifying [`MockBehaviour.Strict`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior) when you create the mock, if you want). This is why Moq silently accepted the call to `StartFolderWatcher` that was actually made by the `ProcessManager`.

You can call `mockFolderWatcher.VerifyNoOtherCalls();` to check that no other unexpected calls were made to your mock.